# Magento 1.9 styles (CSS and JS not found) break frecuently

Tags: css, magento, caching, styles

So, I have a couple Magento sites (1.9.2+) and recently, styles started breaking frequently. By styles breaking I mean home is displayed as only text. All css, js and images are not found.

I know how to fix this. I just clear cache removing *var/cache* and everything is fine again.

My question is... why does this happen periodically and now, more often? I've even setup a cron to delete the cache folder hourly. However, I'm still getting this error.

It's really annoying, and hard to explain to our clients when it's happening daily. "oh, just another cache issue", isn't an acceptable answer for me.

All answers I found so far just fix it once, and never mention it happens periodically.

Any ideas as to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would not set up a cron to clear the cache. So remove that asap. What 3rd party apps have you installed around the time your had these issues. My guess is there must be a process / action that is periodically occurring that causes this change. Check your error logs and exceptions also /magentoroot/var/logs

Last possible reason (although rather slim chance) is you have a sitewide ssl setup but its only valid for certain urls.

Comment: I wouldn't, ideally, setup up a cron for that either, but wanted to try if periodical deletion helped. It does not. I have not installed anything new on one of the sites. No logs or reports whatsoever. No ssl either.